# NoClassDefFoundError javax/ws/rs/core/Application while migrating from jersey 1.18.1 to jersey 1.19

Tags: java, rest, web-applications, jaxb, jersey

When I upgraded the version of jersey I am getting the above exception while try to start my web application.
I am using the jersey library for implementing `JAXBContextResolver` which `implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext>`.
In the exception I see:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Application.
```

Configuration:

```
<jersey-server.version>1.19</jersey-server.version>
<jersey-core.version>${jersey-server.version}</jersey-core.version>
<jersey-servlet.version>${jersey-server.version}</jersey-servlet.version>
<jersey-json.version>${jersey-server.version}</jersey-json.version>
<jersey-client.version>${jersey-server.version}</jersey-client.version>
```

Code:

```
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {
private static final Class<?>[] classes = { Customer.class, Model.class,
        User.class, Workspace.class, AuthResponse.class, Category.class,
        CategoryValue.class };
private JAXBContext context;

public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
    context = new JSONJAXBContext(
            JSONConfiguration.natural().humanReadableFormatting(true)
                    .rootUnwrapping(true).build(), classes);
}

public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
    return context;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to post some code and configuration file

Comment: I just edited my post

Comment: What happens if you explicitly add the [`jsr311-api`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1)?

Comment: @peeskillet so when I added the jsr311.jar not using maven it worked. How can I make it work with maven

Comment: The dependencies you have above should pull it in. You can try to add the dependency explicitly. I linked to it

Comment: I had this dependency before, but it did not worked. Only when I added the jar explicitly it worked (and removed the dependency)

Comment: My mistake. The dependency was with       <scope>provided</scope> thats why I did get it. 
Now everything is working with @peeskillet solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needs to add dependency of jsr311-api and then it worked.

Comment: If anyone can point to the changelog entry, it would be nice. In Jersey 1.17, this was not necessary.